# How to ensure reliable SIGINT handling when using Python's multiprocessing to launch Docker and execute ROS2 nodes?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, signals, python-multiprocessing, ros2

It seems that SIGINT (Ctrl-C) behaviour is very intermittent and unreliable when combining Python's multiprocessing library, Docker and ROS2 nodes.

If you run the following code and Ctrl-C as soon as the nodes start up, you have a good chance of triggering some weird behaviour. In particular, processes don't appear to get properly cleaned up and one node (apparently always the server) is left running in the background.

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing

def process(node):
    subprocess.call(["docker", "run", "-it", "--init", "osrf/ros:foxy-desktop",
                     "bash", "-c", f"ros2 run demo_nodes_py {node}"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nodes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=process, args=(node,))
        for node in ["add_two_ints_server", "add_two_ints_client"]]
    for node in nodes: node.start()
    for node in nodes: node.join()
```

On my setup, Ctrl-C seems to be working fine for each of these tools independently. But when combined only one node seems to receive the SIGINT and terminate, while the other is left running in the background. I've tried all kinds of things, such as ignoring the signal in the child processes and terminating from the parent, or catching the KeyboardInterupt exception and terminating all child process etc etc etc and nothing seems to work.

Can anybody shed any light on how to get this to shutdown cleanly and reliably?